# Convert to a polynomial type integral

Tags: integration, polynomials

I came across a question where I had to convert $\int x^{32}\left(4+7x^3\right)^{2/9}\,dx$ to a "polynomial type integral". I have no idea where to start because I have never seen this type of question before. All I know is that this type of integral appears in engineering.

I cannot distribute the $x^{32}$ term and I also cannot expand $\left(4+7x^3\right)^{2/9}$ so easily. What is the approach to this type of question?

NOTE: I am not necessarily concerned about the answer for this specific integral. I am more interested in the required steps for rewriting the integral so that it is of the polynomial type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let $y = 4+7x^3$ then $dy = 21x^2$ so I would integrate by parts letting $dv = x^2 \left(4+7x^3\right)^{2/9} dx$ and $u = x^{30}$ which will result in $\int x^{30} \left(4+7x^3\right)^{2/9} dx$, thus reducing the degree of the leading polynomial by 2.

Do this 15 times to end up with $\int x^2 \left(4+7x^3\right)^{2/9} dx$, it should be very easy to spot the pattern after the first couple...

Comment: For sure, you are very correct ! I tried to find the pattern and ... I gave up !

Answer (score 2):

Making the problem more general consider
$$I=\int x^a \left(b+c \,x^d\right)^e\,dx$$ For sure, the difficulty happens when $b\neq 0$. Let us rewrite
$$I= b^e\int x^a\left(1+\frac{c }{b}x^d\right)^e\,dx$$ and let $$\frac{c }{b}x^d=y\implies x= \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}y^{\frac{1}{d}} \implies dx=\frac 1 d\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}y^{\frac{1}{d}-1} $$ which, hoping no mistake, would lead to
$$I=\frac{b^{\frac{a+1}{d}+e}}{d\,c^{\frac{a+1}{d}}}\int  y^{\frac{a+1}{d}-1}(1+y)^e\,dy$$ Now
$$(1+y)^e =\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \binom{e}{n}y^n$$ and 
$$I=\frac{b^{\frac{a+1}{d}+e}}{c^{\frac{a+1}{d}}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \frac{ \binom{e}{n} }{a+d n+1}y^{\frac{a+1}{d}+n}$$

Sooner or later, you will learn that
$$I=\int x^a \left(b+c \,x^d\right)^e\,dx=\frac{x^{a+1} }{(a+1)\,b^e}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{a+1}{d},-e;\frac{a+d+1}{d};-\frac{c
   x^d}{b}\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric funtion (whic still hides an infinite sum).

For sure, this is not a closed form. I used what @gt6989b proposed (which is very good) but, after a few integration by parts, I was unable to find the patterns; so my answer.